# How to search Json message in Kibana elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene, kibana

I am using ElasticSearch Kibana dashboard with the following fields

```
host
_id
_score
index
message
```

of which **message** is a json string having values like

```
{"version": "3.4.2", "model": "EX2308", "orders": "50"}
```

I am searching for lucene query to search this JSON message having

```
orders > 30 and version > 3.4
```

Any help is appreciated

**[Updated]**

I am using [logback-elasticsearch-appender](https://github.com/internetitem/logback-elasticsearch-appender) to push messages into ElasticSearch using SLF4j

```
log.info(new org.json.JSONOject(arg).toString());
```

Comment: Does `message` contain a string or a parsed JSON object?

Comment: Parsed JSON object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply input the following Lucene query into the search field:

```
message.orders:>30 AND message.version:>3.4
```

Comment: I am sorry, it is a JSON string stored as "{\"orders\": \"50\", \"version\": \"3.2.2\", \"model\": \"EU21x\"}"

Comment: How do you ingest your documents? You should parse that JSON before indexing the documents into ES.

Comment: Hey, I passed string to store using logStash. Kibana shows it as a JSON

Comment: Update your question with your Logstash config

Comment: Updated my question. Currently I don't have permission to see logstash config

Comment: Thank you. I changed my log to store Parsed JSON string. Now the query you provided is working

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out